# Using smtp mailkit secure or not for sending emails using third party

Tags: smtp, mailkit

While using smtp mailkit to send emails using .net we directly use our email and password for authentication which means sharing our password to third party (smtp mailkit) is it dangerous to work like this.

Smtp.authenticate(email,password)

Can we use like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a risk you have to take unless you decide to implement your own SMTP client library.